# Collision with loaded stl models not working

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I'm having an issue with collision.  While messing around with terrain, I wanted to make a house, for said terrain.  I made a little hexagonal house and exported a STL (I use sketchup web).  It imported just fine, but I can't get any collision.  My test site is here : (giv0.gitlab.io/Fpoy).  I use gitlab because I love the Gitlab web ide and github has nothing like it.

Thanks for any help, but if possible,  I also need to size it down.  I could probably do that on my own, but any efficient was is helpful.  Ignore the terrain you spawn on,  I was testing height maps and mixmaps and textures.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the code used to enable collisions?

Comment: the code used in babylon.js is `newMeshes[0].checkCollisions;`  When importing models I use `let house = newMeshes[0;]` so I can write `house.checkCollisions;` instead.  If you got to the link I have since started using clara.io to export models as .babylon, but if I don't combine all of the meshes, I can't move them as one.  If I could have help with that that would be great.  I found that trick out after I posted but need more help.  Thanks for the response!